# Destroying Objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Recently, I was asked a question in an interview:

> There are 20 objects and 7 need to be destroyed. Write an algorithm to destroy only 7 objects using garbage collector only.

I used to traditional way to destroy the objects using `System.gc()`.

```
public class TestGarbage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            TestGarbage ti = new TestGarbage();
            // System.out.println(ti);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            // Nullifying the reference variable
            TestGarbage ti = null;

            // requesting JVM for running Garbage Collector
            System.gc();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        }

    }

    @Override
    // finalize method is called on object once
    // before garbage collecting it
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Garbage collector called");
        System.out.println("Object garbage collected : " + this);
    }
}

public class TestGarbage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            TestGarbage ti = new TestGarbage();
            // System.out.println(ti);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            // Nullifying the reference variable
            TestGarbage ti = null;

            // requesting JVM for running Garbage Collector
            System.gc();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        }

    }

    @Override
    // finalize method is called on object once
    // before garbage collecting it
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Garbage collector called");
        System.out.println("Object garbage collected : " + this);
    }
}
```

But, the interviewer was not satisfied at all, he asked me that there is no guarantee that above method will definitely run the garbage collector.

So, how can it be solved? I have an understanding that after Java 8 or up versions, the programmers don’t need to take care of destroying the objects that are out of use. The garbage collector takes care of it.

Comment: Your first loop would make each object you create eligible for garbage collection immediately, as there are no strong references to them.  Unless things have changed in the last few years, you can't "destroy" and object.  You can only make it eligible for garbage collection by ensuring that there are no strong references to the object

Comment: As one obvious flaw, you don't preserve the reference to any of the `TestGarbage` objects you create except one during the first loop (meaning 19 objects are already eligible for GC), then the second loop removes the last reference. To preserve 20, you would need a data structure to hold them all (such as an array). To then mark 7 as eligible for GC, you would remove 7 of those references.

Comment: GC is not new in Java 8: it's been there from the start (though it's improved a lot since the early days!). Anyway, you can't ever force an object to get destroyed in Java, so if I were you I'd push back and try to figure out what the interviewer really meant. Maybe they meant [closed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), to free up system resources? If they really meant _destroyed_, I would have pushed back at them, and not worried about not getting a job where the person asking technical questions doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: Hi Amadan, thanks for your input.

Comment: They may have also been getting at [WeakReferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), but who knows. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, after your input I made a few changes:

```
public class TestGarbage {
    public TestGarbage(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        TestGarbage[] testGarbage = new TestGarbage[20];

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            testGarbage[i] = new TestGarbage(i);
            //System.out.println(testGarbage[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            // Nullifying the reference variable
            testGarbage[i] = null;

            // requesting JVM for running Garbage Collector
            System.gc();
            // Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        }

    }

    @Override
    // finalize method is called on object once
    // before garbage collecting it
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Garbage collector called");
        System.out.println("Object garbage collected : " + this);
    }
}
```

But, sometimes garbage collector is called  7 times in the output-

```
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@c7b3681
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@2bcc97e
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@6835df1
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@4381c345
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@169b2a8a
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@7208e61e
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@6ef8517b
```

and some times its only calling only two times-

Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@c7b3681
Garbage collector called
Object garbage collected : TestGarbage@2bcc97e

Comment: As already said, you can't force Java to trash an object, you can only make an object _eligible_ for garbage collection; GC will then decide when and if to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a finalizer method will confuse things. When an object has a finalizer and becomes eligible for collection, the GC will add it to a finalizer list. This list is processed by a separate JVM thread, meaning that the finalizer is not guaranteed to be run at any point (or even before the program exits).

Because of this, each object takes a *minimum* of two GC cycles to be collected.  The first adds it to the finalizer list and, assuming the finalizer gets processed before the next GC, will be collected next time around.  However, it could be many more GC cycles before it gets collected, if ever.

Finalizers have never been a strong feature in Java and the `Object.finalize()` method was deprecated in JDK 9.